# Why do `assert_eq` and `assert_ne` exist when a simple `assert` will suffice?

Tags: unit-testing, rust, assert

`assert!(a == b)` takes less characters than `assert_eq!(a, b)` and, in my opinion, is more readable.

The error messages are more or less the same:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)` (left: `1`, right: `2`)', src\main.rs:41
```

or

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: 1 == 2', src\main.rs:41
```

Actually, this question is not only about Rust; I keep seeing these different assert macros or functions in unit testing frameworks:

- Cpputest has `CHECK` and `CHECK_FALSE` and `CHECK_EQUAL` and so on;
- Googletest has `EXPECT_GT` and `EXPECT_EQ` and so on;
- JUnit has `assertEquals` and `assertFalse` and do on.

Frequently there is also assert for some specific type like string or array. What's the point?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: 1 == 2',

Your example is too simple to see that there is a great advantage in the use of `assert_eq!`. Consider this code:

```
let s = "Hello".to_string();
assert!(&s == "Bye");
```

This is the resulting panic message:

```
'assertion failed: &s == "Bye"'
```

Now let's see what happens when we use `assert_eq!`:

```
let s = "Hello".to_string();
assert_eq!(&s, "Bye");
```

The message:

```
'assertion failed: `(left == right)` (left: `"Hello"`, right: `"Bye"`)'
```

This message provides much more insight than the former. Other unit testing systems often do the same.

Comment: Right. Your test framework is supposed to help you. Simply saying "a test failed" is way less helpful than saying "a test failed *because of these reasons*". There's also the whole aspect of why we create functions with names in the first place - to have readable and understandable code.

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm not sure that assert_eq is more readable by itself but more informative error message is, of course, better.

Comment: @Amomum: There is actually a RFC to improve assert_eq, in the mean time you may be interested in the [pretty_assertions](https://crates.io/crates/pretty_assertions) crate.

Comment: Now the question is: why explicitly say `assert_eq(<expr>, <expr>)`? Wouldn't it be possible to pattern match `assert!(<expr> == <expr>)` and to just do the right thing™?

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Arguably, there is no need for such complications when we have `assert_eq!`. :P

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt's comment resonates with me.  Assuming there is a way to generate equivalent output with `==` and `!=`, creating a new DSL for syntax which already exists in the language seems...  suboptimal.  Sometimes we also need `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`, too, and these do not seem to exist in the assert_* macro DSL.  Puzzling.